# Pandas Select Separate Columns

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

Given the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6],'c':[1,2,3],'d':[4,5,6]})

df
   a  b  c  d
0  1  4  1  4
1  2  5  2  5
2  3  6  3  6
```

I want to select just columns a, c, and d by their column index positions.
I tried the following with no luck:

```
df[df.columns[0],df.columns[-2:]]
```

I can probably figure it out via regular Python, but was wondering if there's a shortcut in pandas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using index `append`

```
df.loc[:,df.columns[[0]].append(df.columns[-2:])]
Out[1363]: 
   a  c  d
0  1  1  4
1  2  2  5
2  3  3  6
```

Or maybe just using `.iloc`

```
df.iloc[:,[0,2,3]]
```

Ummm maybe `np.r_`

```
df.iloc[:,np.r_[0,-2:0]]
Out[1371]: 
   a  c  d
0  1  1  4
1  2  2  5
2  3  3  6
```